# TFS 2010 team project Migration

Tags: tfs, tfs-migration, tfs-to-tfs-migration-tool

Is there any way to move/migrate team projects of a Team project collection from one TFS server to another (both in TFS 2010 version). The destination Team Project collection contains a Team Project already and I want to move the source Team projects in to this particular team projects. So at the end I will have a Team Project which contains several projects in it. Is that possible? I want the history to be preserved as well.

If the above scenario is not possible, can I migrate Team projects from one server to another without going through the database backup-restore-TFS detach-attach process?

I thought of trying the TFSIntegration tool, but could see many people advised to avoid using this due to issues in it.

So if you have any information in accomplishing this, that would be great..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the history then you really only have 2 options:

- TFS Integration platform - http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/
- Back up /restore the collection database - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936138.aspx#Backup

I would recommend moving the database.  This sounds pretty onerous but is actually quite easy.

Good Luck!

Comment: Many thanks for the reply
Also is there anyway to use a script to automate all the migration process? Bcz I do not have direct access the destination machine. So want to create a script so that the admin of the machine can do the task

Answer (score 1):

TFS INTEGRATION PLATFORM used for integration.

A tool which helps a lot named "witAdminUi".